# Build failed with error MSB3721 when building a CUDA SDK example under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, nvidia

I am working on CUDA with Visual Studio 2010. I installed the CUDA toolkit and SDK but one of the SDK examples is not building successfully.

The output console shows:

```
1>_CUDA_Build_Rule:
1>  Compiling with CUDA Build Rule...
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.
1>E:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\Cuda.targets(45,5): error MSB3721: The command "echo "$(CUDA_BIN_PATH)\nvcc.exe"    -arch sm_10 -ccbin "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi   /MTd  " -I"E:\CUDA\include;../../common/inc" -maxrregcount=32  --compile -o "$(IntDir)\$(InputName).cu.obj" "E:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu" 
1>E:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\common\Cuda.targets(45,5): error MSB3721:  "$(CUDA_BIN_PATH)\nvcc.exe"    -arch sm_10 -ccbin "E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin"    -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Zi   /MTd  " -I"E:\CUDA\include;../../common/inc" -maxrregcount=32  --compile -o "$(IntDir)\$(InputName).cu.obj" "E:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA GPU Computing SDK\C\src\bandwidthTest\bandwidthTest.cu"" exited with code 1.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

there is some problem with the nvcc.exe

When i execute nvcc.exe in command prompt, it shows :

`nvcc fatal: No input file specified`

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid yours is a non-programming question.

Anyway, if you run `nvcc` from the command line, you obviously get that error message because you are not specifying which file do you like to compile.

Below, I'm pointing out some other threads with the same problem you detailed. I hope they could be useful to you:

[Visual Studio 2010 - how to fix Error MSB3721 - exiting with code 1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/533797/visual-studio-2010-how-to-fix-error-msb3721-exiting-with-code-1/)

[CUDA Visual Studio 2010 Express build error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396878/cuda-visual-studio-2010-express-build-error)

[Fixing Visual Studio Express error when cleaning 64-bit projects using CUDA 4.1 nvcc compiler](http://uhowto.urbylog.info/post/28837302440/fixing-visual-studio-express-error-when-cleaning-64-bit)